# Connect to mongodb atlas cluster from a kubernetes pod?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes

Unable to connect to mongodb atlas with kubernetes pod. Tried almost everything available on internet, but no luck.

yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: weare-auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: weare-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: weare-auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: weare-auth
          image: <docker-username>/weare-auth
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3001"
      restartPolicy: Always
      dnsPolicy: Default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: weare-auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: weare-auth
  ports:
    - name: weare-auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
```

and here's my express code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import { app } from "./app";

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb://<username>:<password>@test-clus.wpg0x.mongodb.net/auth",
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
      }
    );
    console.log("Connected to mongodb");

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

start();
```

Here are the logs

[Find the screenshot of error logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vnG3.png)

I've masked the credentials. Also I am able to connect to mongodb atlas cluster via shell and Robo3T. Also tried setting up the dnsPolicy like it was mentioned in on the post, but no luck.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Please add logs, otherwise this is going to be a guessing game.

Comment: @F1ko Added screenshot of error logs

Comment: Related topic on Digital Ocean forum: [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/urgent-how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-cluster-from-a-kubernetes-pod). Hi, I'm having difficulty to understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish. Do I understand correct that you are trying to connect from your Kubernetes `Pod` to some external server with `mongodb` and you also have the `Service` to allow pods to communicate with this app from inside of the cluster?

Comment: @DawidKruk Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do. This pod communicates with other pods. But I want to have my data with some managed database provider like mongo-atlas.

Mongo-Atlas provides the **connection srv**. I believe the problem is that, the pod is not communicating with the internet, so it fails to connect to the given connection string.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: The basic troubleshooting should be done on your side to identify if you have issues related to networking/dns resolution or connection to your atlas service. First please try to run a `Pod` with any image and try to curl the external sites like `google.com` and others. If that doesn't work, try to ping some IP's like `8.8.8.8` etc. Here you can find official docs that should help you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/